# Issue: addView with ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I remove  Parent from View but it not working.

The code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) linha.findViewById(R.id.ingredientes_sel);
List views = new ArrayList();

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_obs_carrinho, null);
view.setLayoutParams(
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

if (tipo == 2 || tipo == 3) { //add
    for (int i = 0; i < objetos_add.get(0).length; i++) {
        if (!objetos_add.get(0)[i].equals("")) {
            if (view.getParent() != null)
                ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
            TextView n = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_ingred_carrinho);
            n.setText(objetos_add.get(0)[i]);

            TextView qtd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantidade);
            qtd.setText(objetos_add.get(1)[i]);

            views.add(view);
        }
    }
}
if (tipo == 1 || tipo == 3) { //rem
    for (int i = 0; i < objetos_rem.get(0).length; i++) {
        if (!objetos_rem.get(0)[i].equals("")) {
            if (view.getParent() != null)
                ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
            TextView n = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_ingred_carrinho);
            n.setText(objetos_rem.get(0)[i]);

            TextView qtd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantidade);
            qtd.setText("");

            ImageView add = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.add_ou_rem);
            add.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);

            views.add(view);
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
    root.addView((View) views.get(i)); /* <---- ERRO  */
```

What is wrong?

**EDIT**

Based on this question: [Dynamic layout inflator within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158443/dynamic-layout-inflator-within-a-loop)

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Creating a list of products, using which model a XML layout. The content of this layout is a LinearLayout with 2 texts and one image (inflating this)

Comment: If you want a list, why are you not using an ArrayAdapter?

Comment: I try this, but is very complex, with multiples verify. This option seemed better and work after needed modifications. I used the question link writed in footer of my question (I'll edit) which exemple.

Comment: And based upon all this… why don't you just use a RecyclerView, add a getType and use the type to differentiate between the two view types, while leaving your adapter to deal with the data, which is what it was intended to do to begin with.

Comment: I never use this, I'll go see documentation about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did this once

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_obs_carrinho, null);
```

And then you called `root.addView(view)` multiple times, therefore any `view` you added previously is the exact same, and therefore will have a parent.

---

You need to inflate multiple views that you then add to the root.

So, you can extract out this method

```
private View getCustomView(LayoutInflater inflater, int tipo, List<String[]> data, int pos) {
    // Inflate
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_obs_carrinho, null);
    view.setLayoutParams(
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // Remove parent
    if (view.getParent() != null)
        ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);

    // Find Views
    TextView n = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_ingred_carrinho);
    TextView qtd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantidade);

    // Set views based on type
    if (tipo == 2 || tipo == 3) { // add
        n.setText(data.get(0)[pos]);
        qtd.setText(data.get(1)[pos]);
    } else if (tipo == 1 || tipo == 3) { // rem
        n.setText(data.get(0)[pos]);
        qtd.setText("");
        ImageView add = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.add_ou_rem);
        add.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
    }
    return view;
}
```

And then call it between those two loops.

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);

// tipo = 2 or 3
for (int i = 0; i < objetos_add.get(0).length; i++) {
    if (!objetos_add.get(0)[i].isEmpty()) {
        root.addView(getCustomView(inflater, tipo, objetos_add, i));
    }
}

// tipo = 1 or 3
for (for int i = 0; i < objetos_rem.get(0).length; i++) {
    if (!objetos_rem.get(0)[i].isEmpty()) {
        root.addView(getCustomView(inflater, tipo, objectos_rem, i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand. But, I need interact with objetos_rem too... How do this too without call addView multiple times?

Comment: OK, I'll test soon.

Comment: I would recommend you use custom objects in your list, not what seems to be a `List<String[]>`

Comment: It's work Very good, needing some adjusts too work 100%, but not in your code. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. If I had any typos in my answer, feel free to edit it